# iOS background pattern image transparency shows as black

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I have used the below code:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Background.png")!)

//self.view.layer.opaque = false
//self.view.opaque = false
```

However the transparent parts of the png are black. Any idea how to change this?

The commented out lines are what I have tired but made no diffrence.

Comment: => you try this set alpha of view:-
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)

Comment: Placed before the pattern image had no effect, placed after removed the pattern image completely. Cheers though.

Comment: What color do you expect to see through the transparent parts of the image? If the main view has some transparency you'll see black by default